# How to test the productivity difference between two nurses?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have this data with 60 observations for continues three days hours, in which two nurses work in irregular shifts to cover this whole period:

```
hours   Productivity    Nurse 
1                 50%       A
2                 40%       A
3                 20%       B
4                 10%       A
5                 60%       B
6                15%        B
7                15%        B
.   .   
.   .   
.   .   
60                5%         A
```

I have been asked to build a time series model for the Productivity and decide whether there a strong Productivity difference between nurse A and nurse B. What is the right statistical approach to handle this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Best**

I would use Time Series Regression with dummy variables for the nurses.

I'm actually currently building a similar model for revenue prediction. Basically you include past lags of potential predictors and what is planned tomorrow. In the context of my application, I am incorporating past revenue and what promotional events are planned for tomorrow. What mixture of forward/backward looking variables to include is on a case by case basis.

Obvious sources of potential predictors would be: does each nurse get the same type of patients? Are the patients of the same health? Does day of the week matter? Month? Quarter? Are the patients medicaid, medicare, or private insurance? Demographic characteristics of the patients? Income? Amount of total patients that day? beds filled that day? etc.

**Good**

However, if you have limited data, you could build a separate time series model for each nurse and use the 95% confidence intervals as the basis for decision making. If Nurse A's 95% CI is always greater than Nurse B's, then you can conclude that Nurse A is better than Nurse B. If the confidence intervals overlap, then you don't have enough information or data to make a conclusion other than a Boxplot (median of Nurse A higher than median of Nurse B) or SQL query based heuristics.